# is there any way to change the prices of a quote, after payment method was selected?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I need to make a rule for only one payment method, this rule will changes the price of the products. actually i have a method where i can do that, but i don't know how to save the new price.

```
   class Mipc_Payment_Block_Info_Monthlypayment extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info
{

protected function _prepareSpecificInformation($transport = null)
{
    if (null !== $this->_paymentSpecificInformation) {
        return $this->_paymentSpecificInformation;
    }
    $info = $this->getInfo();
    $transport = new Varien_Object();
    $transport = parent::_prepareSpecificInformation($transport);

        $transport->addData(array(
            $this->__('Plan de pago') => $info->getPaymentPlanTitle(),
            $this->__('Incremento por plan de pago') => round($info->getPaymentPlanIncrement(), 2).'%',
        ));

        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $this->log($item->getProduct()->getName());
            $oldPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
            $newPrice = $oldPrice * ((round($info->getPaymentPlanIncrement(),2) / 100) + 1); //display something like 1.1326
            $item->getProduct()->setPrice$newPrice();
            $item->save();
            $this->log($item->getProduct()->getPrice()); // this shows the new price, but on the step number 5 of OnePage Checkout is showig the oldPrice.
            $this->log("==  == ==");
       }

        return $transport;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to change the product's price permantly or only for that order ?

Comment: Only for  the orders that had selected an specific payment method

Comment: i want to change the product price if "x" payment method is selected.

Comment: Ok referer my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Follow above steps,

1. Add a order placed before event.
2. In that event that is observer.php file add following code

   class Custom_Module_Modulename_Model_Observer

   {
       public function _construct()
       {
       }

   ```
   public function getNewPrice()
   {

       $login  = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
       $roleId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
       $userrole   = Mage::getSingleton('customer/group')->load($roleId)->getData('customer_group_code');
       $userrole   = strtolower($userrole);
       $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
       $cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
       foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
           $productId = $item->getProductId();
           $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
       }
       $batch_qty = $product->getBatchQty();
       $actualPrice = $product->getPrice();
       $specialPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();
       if (isset($batch_qty) && $userrole=="retailer") {
           if (isset($specialPrice)) {
               $newprice = $specialPrice*$batch_qty;
           } else {

               $newprice = $actualPrice*$batch_qty;
           }

       } else {
           $newprice= $actualPrice;
       }

       return $newprice;
   }

   public function updatePrice($observer)
   {
       $event = $observer->getEvent();
       $product = $event->getProduct();
       $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
       $new_price = $this->getNewPrice();
       $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
       //$clasquote_item->save();
       $quote_item->getQuote()->save();
       //Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->save();
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Try with that event that you tell me but it is not possible to execute I have this "sales_quote_payment_import_data_before", which is executed after selecting a payment method.

I may not be very clear and I apologize for that.

In the 5 step of the checkout I need to alter the prices of the products if the customer chooses the payment method 1, I have a model that is executed when the customer accepts the payment method that he chose, right there is where I need to change the prices. I need to know how to alter the quote at the checkout.

Thanks so much for your time.